# Facing "Could not find all of moc, rcc, and uic for Qt5" in omnet++ version 5.7. while installing

Tags: networking, computer-science, omnet++, network-security

I followed every steps of installation manual while installing it. according to the manual, I need to type ./configure. Whenever I typed it, the problem occurred. Showing the exact line"Could not find all of moc, rcc, and uic for Qt5 -- nope, nope, nope"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Before running `./configure` you must always `source setenv` and make sure that all required packages (i.e. qt-default) is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install Qt5 to solve the problem

- sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtcreator